# Convert a buffered stream to pgm in nodejs

Tags: node.js, image, pgm

Is there any way or a library to convert a buffered stream to pgm image format in nodejs. I've searched online but haven't seen one. Kindly guide

Comment: If you mean a **NetPBM** `PGM` image, there's not really much to do as a PGM is just a stream of greyscale bytes with 3 lines of textual header at the start, saying the type, the width and height and the maximum greyscale level. So just put those three lines at the start of the buffer.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the reply. Can you kindly provide a sample please

Comment: It's all here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format